# How can I effectively express the idea of "spraying water around a certain area"?

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

Everything I tried didn't return enough results on Google that allows me to say it's widely used in English.

I tried:

> Spray the (area, space, place) with water.
>
> Sprinkle the (area, space, place) with water.
>
> Spray water around the (area, space, place).
>
> Sprinkle water around the (area, space, place).

But in fact, people reading this would have a cup of water and not a spray, so I don't know if any of the above examples convey what I'm trying to say.

Contextualizing the question: Imagine I have a cup of holy or consecrated water and I'm using it to cleanse the space I live of negative energy. I'm using my fingers to do this.

Comment: 'Sprinkle' is common in ecclesiastical contexts; 'asperse' is a more technical term, which is only like to be recognized by members of churches which employ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are spreading the water with your fingers, spread, sprinkle or splash would be a good verb.  Spread is a general purpose verb that means to cover an area.  Sprinkle usually means spreading slowly and deliberately.  Splash usually means spreading quickly and without much thought.

Comment: Thank you. I've decided for "sprinkle the space with the consecrated water". I've found this in two books about religious practices and I think it might fit the context.